# Undefined index on a valid value, but this value has changed in the if clause?

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, undefined, laravel

Hi I'm working on a timetable class but I have run in the strangest problem.
Usually I figure it out my self pretty quickly but this time it just makes ZERO sense at all

The if clause is as follows:

```
if($start < self::$aStoreHours[$day]['start']){
```

As you can see nothing's wrong here, it gives me an undefined index error, which would tell me the array key does not exists so I use var_dump to return the complete array and I get: (I cut out only the first relevant part)

```
array(6) { [2]=> array(2) { ["start"]=> string(3) "480" ["end"]=> string(4) "1300" }
```

So the key 2 does exist, now I dump the $day variable which returns

```
string(1) "2"
```

Ok this gives 2, well that is strange, so I thought maybe it must be an INT (never had that problem before but in strict languages this is important) so I uses intval, and (int) methods
Now PHP spews Undefined Offset error at me so this is not the problem

Now for the strangest part, the full error is

```
Undefined index: 1
```

So it's trying to tell me, it's trying to call self::$aStoreHours[1] but the $day variable is definitely 2 (Yes the line number is correct and if I dump the $day variable just before it returns 2)

So suddenly the $day variable is either ignored but that would give a null so thats not it, to my knowledge the $day variable is changed to 1 which is a non existent key in the array but it doesn't change

Even stranger, the code worked yesterday without a problem (it is working with timestamps, so not too strange)

I hope the issue has been explained well enough and someone could help me out because this makes no sense to me at all

Note:
Using Laravel framework

Update:
Yes it runs in a function scope, the variable can not change from outside
Larger part of code

```
private static function addTime($day,$start,$end,$title){

    echo $day.':'.$start.':'.$end.':'.$title.'<br>';

    //Check if start isnt lower then opening time, and that end isnt past closing time
    if($start < self::$aStoreHours[$day]['start']){
        $start = self::$aStoreHours[$day]['start'];
    }

    if($end > self::$aStoreHours[$day]['end']){
        $end = self::$aStoreHours[$day]['end'];
    }
```

Comment: So you're saying that if($start < self::$aStoreHours[2]['start']) gives an error?

Comment: Something else is changing `$day` to an invalid value. This isn't the relevant code.

Comment: Yes I would say so to, but nothing is chaning the $day value, and yes that line gives the error:

Look if I do this
"die(var_dump($day));
if($end > self::$aStoreHours[$day]['end']){"

I get 2

If I remove the "die(var_dump($day));"

I get undefined index 1

PLUS: the $day variable is inside a function scope its not changed globally, I will post a larger part of the code with the function start

Comment: Check the value of `$day` after `if` statement.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, how do I do this as laravel throws an exception and stops execution of the code, or do you mean commenting the if statements out because then $day still returns string(1) "2"

Comment: If you do `die(var_dump($day))`, it will terminate in the *first* call to this function. It is possible the notice occurs only in the second/third/... call to this function. Try `if(!array_key_exists($day, self::$aStoreHours)) { /* dump the value of $day, abort script */ }`.

Comment: It's a notification not an error so script should be executed. Even if it does not, comment `if` statement. You need to debug. ;)

Comment: Awesome comment DCoder, I killed it at the first call of addTime, but the problem occured at the 7th call which tried to add a Time for monday(1) which is not available because it's tuesday 2. So my code getting the timestamps from databases selected one to early the problem lays in the SQL query because it is not allowed to parse timestamps from the past THX! THX ALL

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: I will answer this with my own answer, I just have to wait 8-Hours because my rep is too low (I try to avoid asking questions as much as possible, I should start answering some :$)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to helpful comments I found out that the problem did not occur at the first call, but at the 7th call I found this out by adding this part of code

```
if(!array_key_exists($day, self::$aStoreHours)){
 die(var_dump($day));
}
```

While before I was killing it at the first call, but at that time the $day was still correct
As it turns out the timestamp being selected was monday from next week, and it wasn't the SQL query because the script is allowed to get timestamp from past and future as long as the timestamp of today and the last day of the week at closing time is involved

But I cut the timestamps which were longer or shorter then the current time period, sadly my Ending timestamp which I used to cut timestamps laid one day to far giving a timestamp for Monday next week. Which it was trying to parse as Monday this week but that is not allowed since It is tuesday and monday is irrelevant.

Long story short, I have to think out of the box a little more.

Thanks for the help all!